# Testing load, stress, scalability for website

Tags: php, codeigniter, testing, load-testing, stress-testing

I have developed a website in codeigniter (php framework) and want to test its load, stress, scalability . Does any provide this online/offline tool ? Or should I develop a program to test based on our test conditions using any open source api. Please clarify and help.

Comment: Will the profiling class help you? https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/profiling.html

Answer (score 1):

You could try this load test website: http://loadimpact.com (has free test on your website as well as paid options) 
I also found this one: http://siteloadtest.com which appears to be completely free 
There is also http://webpagetest.org, which also appears to be free.
More could be found by a google search of "website stress test"